# SQL Server : create dynamic table based on parameter input

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I want to create a dynamic table based on an input parameter from my report users. When choosing a `ProfitCenterID`, I want this `ProfitCenterID` to be shown as level 1 and all the children `ProfitCenterID` as Level 2 to Level xx.

When the parameter / `ProfitCenterID` is set to “Business Unit A” I need a table with all `ProfitcenterID`’s in this hierarchy. I have an example below showing the desired result.

My `ProfitCenterID`’s are structured as shown in the sample data below. My actual production data has until 19 levels and the user can choose an input value parameter from column `ProfitCenterID`.

My reporting tool is Tableau and I connect to my MS SQL server database with a custom SQL query with parameter.

When:

`ProfitcenterID_Level` is **4** (as it is for "Business Unit A") the WHERE clause must use column `ProfitCenterID_Level_04`

`ProfitcenterID_Level` is **5** (as it is for "Account 1") the WHERE clause must use column `ProfitCenterID_Level_05`

`ProfitcenterID_Level` is **6** (as it is for "D-123400") the WHERE clause must use column `ProfitCenterID_Level_06`

I can't figure out how to create this look up that gives me the `ProfitcenterID_Level` based on the value in `ProfitcenterID`.

*Sample data and desired result examples below.*

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Sample]
(
    ProfitCenterID nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level smallint
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_01 nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_02 nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_03 nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_04 nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_05 nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_06 nchar(30)
    ,ProfitCenterID_Level_07 nchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO [Sample]
VALUES ('Business Unit A','4','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','','',''),
('Account 1','5','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','',''),
('D-123400','6','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123400',''),
('D-123410','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460','D-123410'),
('D-123420','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460','D-123420'),
('D-123430','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460','D-123430'),
('D-123440','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460','D-123440'),
('D-123450','6','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123450',''),
('D-123460','6','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460',''),
('D-123465','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123465'),
('D-123470','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460','D-123470'),
('D-123480','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123460','D-123480'),
('D-123483','6','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123483',''),
('D-123485','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123485'),
('D-123486','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123486'),
('D-123487','6','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123487',''),
('D-123488','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123488'),
('D-123489','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123489'),
('D-123490','6','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490',''),
('D-123491','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123491'),
('D-123492','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123492'),
('D-123493','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123493'),
('D-123494','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123494'),
('D-123495','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123495'),
('D-123496','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123496'),
('D-123497','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123497'),
('D-123498','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123498'),
('D-123499','7','Global Enterprise','Europe','Denmark','Business Unit A','Account 1  ','D-123490','D-123499')
```

[image]

Desired result (when choosing "Business Unit A" - **Level 4**):

```
    SELECT [ProfitCenterID]
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_01]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_02]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_03]
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_04] AS 'Level 01'
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_05] AS 'Level 02'
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_06] AS 'Level 03'
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_07] AS 'Level 04'
      FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Sample]
      WHERE ProfitCenterID_Level_04 = 'Business Unit A' 
 /****** 'Business Unit A' is the input parameter from my report user  ******/
```

[image]

Desired result (when choosing "Account 1"- **Level 5**):

```
    SELECT [ProfitCenterID]
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_01]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_02]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_03]
          -- ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_04]
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_05] AS 'Level 01'
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_06] AS 'Level 02'
          ,[ProfitCenterID_Level_07] AS 'Level 03'
      FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Sample]
      WHERE ProfitCenterID_Level_05 = 'Account 1' 
/****** 'Account 1' is the input parameter from my report user  ******/
```

[image]

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: Please don't post images to display your sample and expected results; they don't help the users you are asking for help from as we can't make use of them. Take the time to post DDL and DML statements, and formatted `text` for your expected results. Don't forget to include your attempts as well.

Comment: Hi both. Thanks for your inputs. I have included my sample data in my answer below.

Comment: ok so your requirement is to get a dynamic table where when you select business unit then business unit column should be display else if you select account then business unit column and row should be skipped and only account should be displayed, correct?

Comment: Also in images you have shown up to level 4 and level 3 so don;t need other levels?

Comment: Hi. That's is correct. I have modified my question with queries that gives me the desired table structure. Only my queries aren't dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my issue. Thank everyone for your inputs. Here is how I solved it.

```
SELECT S.ProfitCenterID, S.ProfitCenterID_Level
    ,CASE 
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 1 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_01
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 2 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_02
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 3 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_03
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 4 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_04
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 5 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_05
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 6 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_06
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 7 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_07
    END AS [Level 1]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 1 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_02
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 2 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_03
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 3 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_04
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 4 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_05
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 5 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_06
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 6 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_07
        -- WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 7 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_08
    END AS [Level 2]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 1 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_03
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 2 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_04
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 3 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_05
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 4 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_06
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 5 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_07
        --WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 6 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_08
        --WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 7 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_09
    END AS [Level 3]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 1 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_04
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 2 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_05
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 3 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_06
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 4 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_07
        --WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 5 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_08
        --WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 6 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_09
        --WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 7 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_10
    END AS [Level 4]
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Sample] AS S
JOIN [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Sample] AS L
ON 'Business Unit A' = L.ProfitCenterID
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 1 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_01
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 2 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_02
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 3 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_03
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 4 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_04
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 5 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_05
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 6 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_06
        WHEN L.ProfitCenterID_Level = 7 THEN S.ProfitCenterID_Level_07
    END = 'Business Unit A'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate the report with sample and was able to achieve the required functionality.

I can share the workbook if needed